# HTML button can't use a different action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a button that will use an action of a different form. From the `Edit` page, I want users to have the option to click a button to run the `Delete` action. This way I can remove the need for the `Delete` view.

Here is my button:

```
<input type="submit" id="yesBtn" value="Yes" class="btn btn-default" style="float:left; background-color:Green; color: white" />
```

I have tried a few things:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "GroupsController", routeValues: new { id = Model.GroupId }, method: FormMethod.Post)){
<input type="submit" id="yesBtn" value="Yes" class="btn btn-default" style="float:left; background-color:green; color: white" />}
```

This uses the form's default `Edit` action; wrapping with

`<form action="~/Views/Groups/Delete.cshtml" method="post"></form>`

doesn't work either, and I also tried an `onclick` event with no success.
I think the BeginForm isn't being recognized for some reason.

Here is my action code, I am trying to pass in the `Model.GroupId`:

```
// POST: AspNetGroups/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    AspNetGroup aspNetGroup = db.AspNetGroups.Find(id);
    db.AspNetGroups.Remove(aspNetGroup);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is the relevant part of my view:

```
@model ContactManager.Models.AspNetGroup
...
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    ...
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <h2>Delete Group</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>You are about to delete group placeholder.</p>
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete it?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <form action="~/Views/Groups/Delete.cshtml" method="post">
                        <input type="submit" id="yesBtn" value="Yes" class="btn btn-default" style="float:left; background-color:green; color: white" />
                    </form>
                    <input type="button" id="noBtn" value="No" class="btn btn-default" style="float:left; background-color:red; color: white" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
}
```

Comment: u sure controller name is GroupsController ?  'controller'  is commonly omitted.

Comment: @Nico I think you're right! But it didn't solve my problem (the `Delete` button is still using the `Edit` action after changing this). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not valid to use form inside form in html. By clicking 'delete' button you submitting your outer form rendered by Html.BeginForm() helper. So you should to make the delete button as a link, or take this inner form outside of outer form.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was starting to think this was the case too after some research, but you confirmed it. Appreciate the help and especially a suggestion.